# get menulink id from enitity id?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, navigation

Id like to be able to get a link content ID from an entity id. Not sure how to best do this?  I'm trying to render a menu tree and use a specific taxonomy term as the menu tree root. I have access to the taxonomy entity but I don't know how to get the menu link content id i.e. 'menu_link_content:e4f3fc49-98d8-4f20-952f-8ed08f9cbfcb' => string(54) "menu_link_content:e4f3fc49-98d8-4f20-952f-8ed08f9cbfcb"

Comment: Any entity has an ID (autoincremented integer) and a UUID (long hash key). What type of id (ID or UUID) from which entity (term or menu link) you have and what you want to get?

Comment: I was trying to find the menu link id i.e. `e4f3fc49-98d8-4f20-952f-8ed08f9cbfcb` for a given term that happens to be referenced in the menu as a link.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rendering the entire menu tree, flattening it, then searching for the specific term ID. I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

```
if (empty($entity) || $entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'node' && $entity->getType() == 'product') {
  return;
}

$menu_name = 'main';
$menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
$menu_link_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link');
$parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_name);

// Get menu link ID from field placement term.
if (sizeof($parameters->activeTrail) === 1 && $entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'node'  && !empty($entity->get('field_placement')->getValue())) {
  $term_id = $entity->get('field_placement')->getValue()[0]['target_id'];
  $parameters->onlyEnabledLinks();
  $flat_tree = $menu_tree->load($menu_name, $parameters);
  $flat_tree_manipulators = array(
    array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:flatten'),
  );
  $flat_tree = $menu_tree->transform($flat_tree, $flat_tree_manipulators);
  foreach ($flat_tree as $link) {
    $params = $link->link->getRouteParameters();
    if (!empty($params['taxonomy_term']) && $params['taxonomy_term'] == $term_id) {
      // Set matched route as id or parent.
      $currentLinkId = $link->hasChildren ? $link->link->getPluginId() : $link->link->getParent();
    }
  }
}

// Render menu tree from route.
$currentLinkId = isset($currentLinkId) ? $currentLinkId : reset($parameters->activeTrail);
$parameters->setRoot($currentLinkId);
$parameters->setMinDepth(1);
$parameters->onlyEnabledLinks();

$tree = $menu_tree->load($menu_name, $parameters);
```